# How to solve this Russian Olympiad problem (1977) (+algorithm version)?

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

How to prove/solve this problem (with some steps/algorithm in creating a solution):

> You are given a set of scales and a set of n different weights. R
>   represents the state in which the right pan is heavier, L represents
>   the state in which the left pan is heavier and B represents the state
>   in which the pans balance. Show that given any n-letter string of Rs
>   and Ls you can put the weights onto the scales one at a time so that
>   the string represents the successive states of the scales. For
>   example, if the weights were 1, 2 and 3 and the string was LRL, then
>   you would place 1 in the left pan, then 2 in the right pan, then 3 in
>   the left pan.

Problem found at [11th ASU 1977 (problem 16)](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/aditya/www.kalva.demon.co.uk/soviet/sov77.html).
This problem can be also solved with an algorithmic solution since there is a identical problem [here](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1481).